# How can we to trigger Cypress tests via some Cypress/Custom API call?

Tags: cypress

I do have a console and web application to test via automation.

1. I have created a few automation tests for console using **UiPath**,
2. And using **Cypress** I have created automation tests for web application.

Now I am trying to implement the automatic continuous execution, here is the flow:

1. I will run UiPath tests via API call, and I will store some output values,
2. Once above execution gets over, I need to pass those output values to Cypress tests(as a parameter) and want to trigger them automatically, Using command: `$ cypress run` we can trigger the cypress tests manually, but I am just wondering if there is some kind of API using which I can pass the data to cypress tests and trigger them.

For example: If I hit [www.my-server-address.com/path-to-tests/cypress.sh](http://www.my-server-address.com/path-to-tests/cypress.sh) it should run the cypress tests on that server, but I am just wondering if there is a built-in Cypress feature which allows us to do that.

Any custom solutions are also welcome!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leverage travis.ci or any other form of continuous integration. Here is an example .travis.yml file

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 10
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      # Ubuntu 16+ does not install this dependency by default, so we need to install it ourselves
      - libgconf-2-4
cache:
  # Caches $HOME/.npm when npm ci is default script command
  # Caches node_modules in all other cases
  npm: true
  directories:
    # we also need to cache folder with Cypress binary
    - ~/.cache
install:
  - npm ci
script:
  - $(npm bin)/cypress run --record
```